# Saving my GeoPandas symbology

Tags: qgis, python, shapefile, geopandas

I would like to save a specific symbology to a property of my dataframe and use it as default parameter whend the file is opened in for example QGIS.

Is it possible ?

if yes what would be the following steps after the GeoPandas main example:

```py
import geopandas as gpd

world = gpd.read_file(geopandas.datasets.get_path('naturalearth_lowres'))

# Plot by GDP per capta
world = world[(world.pop_est>0) & (world.name!="Antarctica")]
world['gdp_per_cap'] = world.gdp_md_est / world.pop_est
world.plot(column='gdp_per_cap', cmap='viridis')

# save the symbology 

# save the file 
world.to_file('toto.shp')
```

Comment: It should be theoretically possible but it is not implemented. You would have to figure out how to map geopandas/matplotlib style to QML.

Comment: I actually don't need the matplotlib one for now so I'm only interested in the geopandas -> QML one. I'll check the output of a .qml file when I export the style and see what I can do